# Bridge words - word pairs linked by the front and back

Tags: wordplay, english

Wanted to try out a new puzzle.  Doesn't seem like an original idea, so the concept may already be out there.  Please let me know if so and I'll put a link back to it.  Also, not sure if it will be too easy or too hard, so please add your comments below. *(Edit: I've made a second such puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24094/bridge-words-2-word-pairs-linked-by-their-front-and-back))*

> Find a pair of "bridge words" to fill in the gaps of the sentences below.  Bridge words are words where the last $n\geq3$ letters of the first word are the same as the first $n$ letters of the second word.  The words must then both be more than $n$ letters long.

For example:
Q: I hurled away boredom.  I flung away drabness.  I _______ _______.
A: I catapul**ted** **ted**iousness.

Okay, here goes:

1. Sometimes we torture people.  Sometimes we don't.  We ______ our ______.
2. I object to objects.  In fact, I have a ______ for _______.
3. I measured our location through the _______, while keeping track of our distance on the _______.
4. The trouble with _________ _________, is that kids and drunkards end up dancing on them.
5. Despite his __________ tone, my sense were all ______.
6. The runny-nosed trebuchet operating was basically a ________ ________.
7. It's much smaller, but leaves a remainder.  It's an ______ _______. (This is quite a technical word)
8. I don't care about the strength.  _________ is _________.
9. If ________ your _______ is confirmed, you may be eligible to become king!
10. They punched each other without speaking.  The _______ were rather _____.

Hint:

> $n\geq4$ and mostly $n=5$.

Comment: Are the words always in the order of your example, or are they sometimes swapped?

Comment: can the two words be the same word?

Comment: The words are always in order. They could be the same in theory, but none of them are.

Comment: One clarification that I've added above.  There must be at least $n+1$ letters in each word.  So "tormentor-tormentor", "murmur-murmur", "hotshots-hotshots" would be valid bridge pairs, but "here-here" would not.

Comment: I just wanted to reiterate how much I love this puzzle. I'm sad I got here too late to do all of them, but even filling in the missing few answers was a ton of fun. I definitely vote in favor of more of these!

Comment: @victorhenry, thanks for your remarks. I'll work on another

Comment: On reflection, I'm going to award the 100 bonus points to @APrough, who got most of them.  VictorHenry, you'll have to get the next one!  I hope that's okay with everyone

Comment: @VictorHenry, I've made another one. Link at the top of my post...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Since several people have provided different parts of the answer, I figured it made sense to make a single community-wiki answer that pulls together all the parts.*</sup>

---

1. Sometimes we torture people. Sometimes we don't. We ______ our ______.

> intersperse/persecution

2. I object to objects. In fact, I have a ______ for _______.

> loathing/things

3. I measured our location through the _______, while keeping track of our distance on the _______.

> astrodome/odometer

4. The trouble with _________ _________, is that kids and drunkards end up dancing on them.

> unstable/tables

5. Despite his __________ tone, my sense were all ______.

> accommodating/atingle

6. The runny-nosed trebuchet operating was basically a ________ ________.

> snuffling flinger

7. It's much smaller, but leaves a remainder. It's an ______ _______.

> piddling lingerer or aliquot quotient

8. I don't care about the strength. _________ is _________.

> Sturdiness/inessential

9. If ________ your _______ is confirmed, you may be eligible to become king!

> perchance/ancestry

10. They punched each other without speaking. The _______ were rather _____.

> fighters/terse

Comment: A lot of these are really clever, I'm a big fan of this puzzle. My only concerns are 1 and 7. For number 1, the first two sentences are in the past tense, and then the answer suddenly switches to present tense. Obviously intersperse/persecution no longer works if you put a 'd' on the end of intersperse, but it's such a clever answer I suspect it's the intended one. As for number 7, the first word needs to start with a vowel sound since it's preceded by "an". Again, though, I'm a huge fan of the given answer.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I just got the intended answer for #7: "aliquot quotient". I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks!  I will award the bounty when I can.  I had in mind surmountable tables for 4, but obviously unstable is as good.  For number 7, I had something else in mind.

Comment: @VictorHenry, good catch on the tense in #1.  I'll fix the question

Answer (score 4):

1.Sometimes we torture people. Sometimes we don't. We ______ our ______.

> 

2.I object to objects. In fact, I have a ______ for _______.

> loathing/things

3.I measured our location through the _______, while keeping track of our distance on the _______.

> 

4.The trouble with _________ _________, is that kids and drunkards end up dancing on them.

> portable/tables - Thanks to @GentlePurpleRain

5.Despite his __________ tone, my sense were all ______.

> disbelieving/ingrained

6.The runny-nosed trebuchet operating was basically a ________ ________.

> snuffling flinger

7.It's much smaller, but leaves a remainder. It's an ______ _______.

> piddling lingerer

8.I don't care about the strength. _________ is _________.

> 

9.If ________ your _______ is confirmed, you may be eligible to become king!

> perchance/ancestry

10.They punched each other without speaking. The _______ were rather _____.

> fighters/terse

Comment: Good start. 2 and 10 are right. 4 is half right, though pretty good.

Comment: I was thinking `portable tables` for #4.

Comment: I definitely like some of your alternative answers. Particularly 5.

Comment: I've clarified a rule, which rules out here/heredity.  Both words need to be $n+1$ letters long.

Comment: @DrXorile What about "there"?

Comment: @f'', there/heredity would be fine.  there/here would not.

Comment: Correct: 2, 6, 9, 10.  Your number 7 is very good - the answer I was looking for is a somewhat technical mathematical term. You're close on number 4 - the adjective is a description of a kind of table that allows this kind of behaviour.

Comment: I also now realise that number 5 is poorly specified, in that there could be many many answers.  The last word fits idiomatically, especially in the UK.  But it leaves many possible answers for the first word.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that #1 is `intersperse / persecution`

Comment: 4 must be "unstable tables". Is 5 supposed to be "senses" instead of "sense"?

Comment: Do you want more clues for this or are you still working on it?

Comment: Yeah I think GentlePurpleRain had the right idea of a community answer.  I was stumped on a lot of those.  Plus I sense a culture difference on some of the answers (British vs. American), but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I believe 3 is [astrodome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrodome_(aeronautics))/odometer.

8 could be a lot of things, I think. The second word is "inessential", so the first word is any synonym for strength that ends in -iness, such as "sturdiness" or "brawniness".

Edit: #7 I think was meant to be "aliquot quotient".

Comment: Woohoo!  @DrXorile: Give the bounty to VictorHenry for filling in the missing pieces!

Comment: Why don't you update the community-wiki answer with your solution for #7?  It sounds better to me.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, I've marked your wiki entry as correct, and will award the bounty that way also.  However, if you would like to re-award you could simply add the bounty back!

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Done and done! I forgot there was a community wiki answer, I'm used to adding answers in comments for these kinds of puzzles. =P

Comment: @DrXorile I didn't come up with any solutions, so please don't give me the bounty.  I just amalgamated them into a coherent answer.  It was VictorHenry who filled in all the missing pieces.

Comment: I thought of quotient but didn't find aliquot as its pair. Good work.

Answer (score 2):

5. Despite his __________ tone, my senses were all ______.

   > accommodATING ... ATINGling

Comment: That's close enough. I had atingle, rather than atingling, and I realize that there are 100s of words ending in -ating.