# Bridge words 2 - word pairs linked by their front and back

Tags: wordplay, english

I made a puzzle earlier ([Bridge words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23941/bridge-words-word-pairs-linked-by-the-front-and-back)), and thought I'd make another (encouraged by a request from [@VictorHenry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10861/victorhenry)).

> Find a pair of "bridge words" to fill in the gaps of the sentences below.  Bridge words are words where the last $n\geq3$ letters of the first word are the same as the first $n$ letters of the second word.  The words must then both be more than $n$ letters long ("hots**hots-hots**hots" would be a valid bridge pair ($n=4$), but "here-here" would not be).

For example:
Q: Sometimes we torture people. Sometimes we don't. We ______ our ______.
A: We inters**perse** our **perse**cution.

Okay, here goes:

1. Good climbers leave the _______ ________.
2. I caught _____ of the person _______ in the pool.
3. She lives far out on the ______, ______ from society.
4. I could see that the glamorous lady was ______ _______ that caught the light.
5. We've ______ all the evidence and concluded that alcoholism is _______.
6. The dentist used an odd ______ to save information about her patient's ______.
7. I was sick in the West Indies, but in the ______ I was the ______.
8. I take a coat and dress out of the wardrobe,  ______ the _______, and return them.
9. Grimm's _________ was left ______ after the queen guessed his name.
10. The king said to the regent: "I'll be back tomorrow, so you must _____ _______."

Hint:

> $n$ is equal to 5 or 6.

Comment: Couple of slight tweaks to some of the clues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hooray! These seem harder but I'm making progress. Going to go ahead and post this to keep track of which ones I've solved so far.

1. Good climbers leave the _______ ________.

> mountain untainted

2. I caught _____ of the person _______ in the pool.
3. She lives far out on the ______, ______ from society.
4. I could see that the glamorous lady was ______ _______.
5. We've ______ all the evidence and concluded that alcoholism is _______.

> gathered/hereditary

6. The dentist used an odd ______ to save information about her patient's ______.

> filename/enamel

7. I was sick in the West Indies, but in the ______ I was the ______.

> Antilles/illest

8. I took two coats out of the wardrobe to ______ the two _______.

> launder / [undercoats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_(clothing)#Coats.2C_jackets_and_overcoats)

9. Grimm's _________ was left ______ when the queen guessed his name.

> Rumpelstiltskin/tsking

10. The king said to the regent: "I'll be back tomorrow, so you must _____ _______."

> govern overnight

Comment: 9. Interest restored?

Comment: 4. Dressed seductively , maybe

Comment: @DrunkWolf, I think I like that better than my solution to nine, but it might not match with Dr Xorile's hint.

Comment: @JTL ah ok, I tend not to read hints

Comment: Great job. I've made slight tweaks to some of the clues to clarify some of them.

Comment: All but number 8 have been mentioned. Great work. Your 8 fits well, but is not what I intended... I'll think about a tweak to the clue.

Comment: I tweaked clue 8 to make it less ambiguous.  Have a go at it!!

Answer (score 5):

I have a few to add to the ones [@VictorHenry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10861/victorhenry) already solved.  My solution for number nine feels weak.

3.She lives far out on the ______, ______ from society.

> peninsula/insulated

2.I caught _____ of the person _______ in the pool.

> glimmers/immersed

9.Grimm's _________ was ______ when the queen guessed his name.

> printer/interested ???  spinner/innerved ??? This seems like it should be Rumpelstiltskin-related...

Comment: Great job. I've made slight tweaks to some of the clues to clarify some of them.

Comment: @DrXorile Now wearing earrings seems to fit even more.